# issues in html css design textbox disabled?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

Hai i develop an application in android phoneGap.I used html css for Designing Purpose and It is working Fine.But when I type in the text box my design is collapsing.I have attached my form.kindly go through it and clear my issues.

[image: This is Design]

But while I type the text in these text Box,my Form is like this[image]

In these my another textbox is diabled. How can i recitify this problem?

My code
**update**
    
    
      
       
        
        PhoneGap

```
     <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
     <style type="text/css">
     #footer {
    position:absolute; z-index:2;
    top:92%;bottom:32px; left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:18px;
    padding:0;
}
input:focus{//update
outline: none;
 }

.ex21{

    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-color:#FBB917;

    border: 1px solid;
  background:url('searchbtn.PNG' ) repeat-y right;
  padding-right:20px;

    }
.ex2{

    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-color:#FBB917;

    border: 1px solid;


    }
    .searchbox input {
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

margin-top:0.2cm;

margin-left:1cm;
width:70%;
height: 32px;
float: left;
font-size:15pt;
padding: 2px;
border-top: 4px solid orange;
border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
border-left: 4px solid orange;

}
.sea input {
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
margin-top:0.2cm;

background-image: url(sea.PNG);
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold; 

width:10%; 
height: 43px;
border: 0;
float: left;
border-top: 4px solid orange;
border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
border-right: 4px solid orange;
}
    .invitebox input {
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

margin-top:0.2cm;

margin-left:1cm;
width:70%;
height: 32px;
float: left;
font-size:15pt;
padding: 2px;
border-top: 4px solid orange;
border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
border-left: 4px solid orange;

}
.invitebtn input {
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
margin-top:0.2cm;

background-image: url(sea.PNG);
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold; 

width:10%; 
height: 43px;
border: 0;
float: left;
border-top: 4px solid orange;
border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
border-right: 4px solid orange;
}


    </style>
  </head>

  <body >

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
             <td> <label style="font-size:12pt">Search Names</label></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

  <br>  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>


            <td><label style="font-size:12pt">Choose one of the following options to search our directory of Names</label></td>
            <td></td>

            <td></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <div align="center">
    <div class="searchbox"><input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox"></div>
<div class="sea"><input name="search" type="button" id="btn"></div>
</div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
        <br/>

      <br/>
        <br/>
      <br/>
     <table>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>

   <td></td>

   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><input value='' type='radio' id='one'/><label>Limit Search Results to Name</label></td>

   </tr>
   </table>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div align="center">

            <label style="font:bold;font-size:15pt">OR</label>
        </div>
      <br>
      <div id="loadingScreen" align="center"></div>
    <div align="center">
    <div class="invitebox"><input type="text" name="invitebox" id="invitebox" ></div>
<div class="invitebtn"><input name="invite" type="button" ></div>
</div>

     <div id="footer">
        <div style="border-width:3px;border-height:6px;background-color:#00458D;" align="center">
         <table>


         <input type="button" value="Button1" style="width:20%" />
         <input type="button" value="Button2" style="width:20%" />

         <input type="button" value="Button3" style="width:20%"/>
         <input type="button" value="Button4" style="width:20%" />
         </table>
         </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/Mgc3t/) for you. I had added the outline border code also given by @Darthur. There is no issue with your HTML or CSS. Please check that jsfiddle. Problem may be with your javascript files.

Comment: its working in version android-15,its not working in android-8(2.2)

Comment: i wont add any script in this application just design only

Comment: But you can see in that jsfiddle example, none of the textbox is disabling when typing.

Comment: R u trying in android 2.2 version?

Answer (score 0):

This is the outline border, which is displayed on focus.

You can disable it for all `input` elements by adding this to your CSS:

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Please note that if the background of the window is different than white you will need to alter the color.

Comment: @Dathur again it look like this i have updated my code kindly go through it

Comment: It is probably using the webkit function. I have updated the code in my answer above and I included the webkit function.

Comment: @Darthur His  problem is not outline border. When he types on first textbox, the second one is not seeing.

Comment: @libin thats problem and also while typing text in second text box .